# Selecting from date range mysql/phpmyadmin problem

Tags: mysql, sql

For my current project I'm using XAMPP. I have a problem on pulling data from a date range, sorry for the messy title I don't know how to word it out. The problem is I'm pulling dates from 06/01/2020 to this day 06/16/2020 however it doesn't display the data for today, but when my end date is 06/17/2020 (which is tomorrow at least in my country) it appears. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use only greater or less `>`,`<` operators or also with equal values `<=`,`>=`?

You can also use BETWEEN function in your query.

```
WHERE date BETWEEN CAST('2020-06-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2020-06-16' AS DATE);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
WHERE date >= CAST('2020-06-01' AS DATE)
AND date <= CAST('2020-06-16' AS DATE);
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but the results are still the same. This is the first time I have encountered this. Weird. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it, I used `SELECT * FROM data WHERE date(date) BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-16';` if someone's look for this too, please try this out :)

Comment: You are probably storing date and time information in your field. It works the way you are expecting when you type cast it to date because you remove the time information. '2020-06-16 00:01' is greater than '2020-06-16'.

Comment: but I don't get why data for 06/16 isn't displayed, weird.